# Sorted objects are not passing to string variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, sorting, object

i tried to do sorting on a html table on my own style using javascript objects sort method. I have a very peculiar problem. 
1. I passed all the table data(cell values) to a assigned object.. DONE!!!
2. Then I sorted that object values using object.sort... DONE !!!
3. Now after sorting i want to assign the sorted rows back to the table.. here i got stuck.. i get sorted rows. But when i assign it to a variable inside forloop, it gets assigned to the 'nTable' variable. After completing the loop and when it comes out the 'nTable' variable gets empty.. I tried with string conversions and lot of things. but am not able to find it out. Please help. Thanks in advance. Below is my code

```
    function doSort(ColNo)
    {

        var objCols =[];
        var totalRows =  document.getElementById('cities').rows.length;

        for (var i=1; i < totalRows; i++)
        {
            var x = document.getElementById('cities').rows[i].cells;                
            objCols [i]= {rIndex:i, cellVal:x[ColNo].innerHTML};
        }

        objCols.sort(function(a, b)
        {
            var x = a.cellVal.toLowerCase();
            var y = b.cellVal.toLowerCase();
            if (x < y) {return -1;}
            if (x > y) {return 1;}
            return 0;
        });

        var nTable = '<table id="cities" style="border:solid;">';
        nTable += '<thead style="text-align:center; background-color:green; color:white">';
        nTable += '<tr>';
        nTable += '<th onclick="doSort(this.cellIndex)">Indian Cities</th>';
        nTable += '<th onclick="doSort(this.cellIndex)">State</th>';
        nTable += '</tr>';
        nTable += '</thead>';
        nTable += '<tbody>';


            for (i = 1; i < totalRows; i++)
            {
                var rowNo = objCols[i].rIndex;

                nTable += '<tr>' + document.getElementById('cities').rows[rowNo].innerHTML + '</tr>';
            }

            alert (nTable);
        nTable + ='</tbody>';
        nTable + ='</table>';

        document.getElementById('cities').innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById('cities').innerHTML = nTable;       
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="cities" style="border:solid;">
        <thead style="text-align:center; background-color:green; color:white">              
            <tr>
                <th onclick="doSort(this.cellIndex)">Indian Cities</th>
                <th onclick="doSort(this.cellIndex)">State</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Coimbatore</td>
                <td>Tamilnadu</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Chennai</td>
                <td>Tamilnadu</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Madurai</td>
                <td>Tamilnadu</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hyderabad</td>
                <td>Andhra Pradesh</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mumbai</td>
                <td>Maharashtra</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Panaji</td>
                <td>Goa</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Delhi</td>
                <td>Delhi</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bangalore</td>
                <td>Karnataka</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Calicut</td>
                <td>Kerala</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Kolkota</td>
                <td>West Bengal</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    function doSort(ColNo)
      {
     var objCols =[];
     var totalRows =  document.getElementById('cities').rows.length;

    for (var i=0; i < totalRows; i++)
    {
        var x = document.getElementById('cities').rows[i].cells;                
        objCols [i]= {rIndex:i, cellVal:x[ColNo].innerHTML};
    }

     objCols.sort(function(a, b)
     {
        var x = a.cellVal.toLowerCase();
        var y = b.cellVal.toLowerCase();
        if (x < y) {return -1;}
        if (x > y) {return 1;}
        return 0;
      });

       var nTable = '<table id="cities" style="border:solid;">';
       nTable += '<thead style="text-align:center; background-color:green; color:white">';
    nTable += '<tr>';
    nTable += '<th onclick="doSort(this.cellIndex)">Indian Cities</th>';
    nTable += '<th onclick="doSort(this.cellIndex)">State</th>';
    nTable += '</tr>';
    nTable += '</thead>';
    nTable += '<tbody>';


        for (i = 0; i < totalRows; i++)
        {
           if(objCols[i]) { 
           var rowNo = objCols[i].rIndex;
            nTable += '<tr>' + document.getElementById('cities').rows[rowNo].innerHTML + '</tr>';
           }
        }
    nTable +='</tbody>';
    nTable +='</table>';

    document.getElementById('cities').innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById('cities').innerHTML = nTable;       
}
```

Your shorthand operator is like **+ =**. It should be **+=**

See the changed code. It works and you get your sorted data.

**EDIT:**
Here's a fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/f0L0s674/2/

Comment: Beware, this adds the headers as new rows each time you sort. Starting the loops from 1 was likely to prevent this.

Comment: @takendarkk Yes I have observed that. The OP has to change his code to fix that

Comment: Actually, you changed it to 0 - OP had it start at 1 which was correct.

Comment: @takendarkk tryin to fix my fiddle as per

Comment: oh.. thanks a lot dude... it works... am new to javascript and web programming.. am from visual basic programming. thanks once again

Comment: @srinivasan I've updated the fiddle. It works fine now.